# Excel VBA How to replace each cells containing numbers greater than zero

Tags: excel, vba

How can I replace numbers greater than zero in a range?

I can replace one specific word or number in a given range:

```
Sheet1.Columns("N").Replace What:="1", Replacement:="Good", LookAt:=xlWhole, 
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

Now, what if I want to replace all that contains numbers greater than zero like `1-1000000` which will make the macro run slow if I use looping statements.

I was hoping there could be a code like:

```
Sheet1.Columns("N").Replace What:=">0", Replacement:="Good", LookAt:=xlWhole,
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a filter:

```
Sub tgr()

    On Error Resume Next    'Prevents error if there are no cells with value >0
    With Intersect(Sheet1.UsedRange, Sheet1.Columns("N"))
        .AutoFilter 1, ">0"
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "Good"
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0         'Remove the On Error Resume Next condition

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for the use of `.Autofilter` :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use =EVALUATE(), but the following should not be too slow:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range, rFix As Range, rr As Range
    Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("N:N"))
    Set rFix = Nothing
    For Each rr In r
        If IsNumeric(rr.Value) Then
            If rr.Value > 0 Then
                If rFix Is Nothing Then
                    Set rFix = rr
                Else
                    Set rFix = Union(rr, rFix)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    rFix.Value = "Good"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Gary, this might not be what I'm looking for. If it will be a long code like this, I'd probably just do another column and put a formula on it based on the main column as it would run faster.:(

Comment: If mine is too slow use **tigeravatar's** macro

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub PositiveIsGood()
For x = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Cells(x, "N") > 0 Then
        Cells(x, "N") = "Good"
    End If
Next x
```

End Sub

Comment: Sorry Mark, I can do loops but I don't want to use loops as much as possible as they go each rows to check and we will be having thousands of records each day. Isn't there an option like the Sheet1.Columns("N").Replace which is one liner and replaces all qualified cell values in a column? I was hoping there would be.