# Replacing zero values with "No" and greater than zero with "Yes" on multiple sheets in multiple columns based on header

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I provide clients with a list of products and their availability. Putting it together is time intensive.

The source product lists, which are broken up by category, do not always contain the same number of availability columns. One category may have two columns, listing availability today and by end of this month, another may have more visibility, with up to 6 columns, listing availability today and by end of month out up to five months.
Additionally, management does not want the actual available quantities to be sent out.

I've been creating formulas for each sheet, but to save time, and provide them more frequently, I'm developing a Macro Enabled template. I would like to maintain the separate category sheets in a compiled workbook.

There are some extra detail columns that I was able to remove using macros, but this is how each sheet is coming down to.

Sheet 1

| Model | SKU | Feb 27 | Feb 28 | March 31 | April 30 | UPC | Details | Dealer | MAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fam 1 | Fam1-A | 0 | 0 | 120 | 240 | 12345678 | blahdy | $500 | $600 |
| Fam 2 | Fam2-A | 0 | 35 | 35 | 70 | 23456789 | blahblah | $750 | $850 |

Sheet 2

| Model | SKU | Feb 27 | Feb 28 | March 31 | UPC | Details | Dealer | MAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kid 1 | Kid1-A | 15 | 85 | 140 | 98765432 | nope | $100 | $0 |
| Kid 2 | Kid2-A | 0 | 12 | 12 | 87654321 | stillnaw | $200 | $250 |

This is what I'm trying to accomplish with more macros:

Sheet 1

| Model | SKU | Feb 27 | Feb 28 | March 31 | April 30 | UPC | Details | Dealer | MAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fam 1 | Fam1-A | NO | NO | YES | YES | 12345678 | blahdy | $500 | $600 |
| Fam 2 | Fam2-A | NO | YES | YES | YES | 23456789 | blahblah | $750 | $850 |

Sheet 2

| Model | SKU | Feb 27 | Feb 28 | March 31 | UPC | Details | Dealer | MAP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kid 1 | Kid1-A | YES | YES | YES | 98765432 | nope | $100 | $0 |
| Kid 2 | Kid2-A | NO | YES | YES | 87654321 | stillnaw | $200 | $250 |

I've been successful so far by entering into cell I2 on each sheet

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(C$1),IF(C2>0,"YES","NO"),"Dont copy")
```

then filling the formula down and across based on the table size, and then pasting the values into the table. Don't copy being a note for myself not to copy that column into the table if I overshoot the table size.

I did find, test, and confirm that this code will change whole cell values of "0" to "NO".

```vb
Sub ChangeZero()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set rng = sh.Columns("C:H")
        rng.Replace "0", "NO", xlWhole
    Next    
End Sub
```

I had set range as C:H, as the product category with the most visibility for availability only goes out to that column, but then a $0 MAP (minimum advertised price) is converted to a "NO" if it is a product category with very low visibility. Haven't been able to find a way to exclude just that column on that sheet, or exclude just that header.

Lastly, to replace numbers greater than "0 with "YES", I tried basically the same sub but with `rng. replace ">0", "YES", xlWhole`, but it does nothing.
I saw [Excel VBA How to replace each cells containing numbers greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921787/excel-vba-how-to-replace-each-cells-containing-numbers-greater-than-zero), but couldn't figure out how to recode it to cover the whole worksheet.

Comment: So what you are looking for is to select the range, based on if row 1 has a date, and use this range to replace the values?

Comment: You could try `rng.replace "<>0", "YES", xlWhole`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for column C:H, if C is fix but H is not fix, then if the columns to check will always be in between header SKU (where SKU is fix in column B) and UPC (not fix), maybe you can try to find what columns is the UPC header on each sheet. Then use the result - 1 as the replacement of H in your `set rng`.

Comment: @Aldert Yes, but across all sheets.

Comment: @user10186832 Thank you. Tried it, but it does nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: @karma That is correct, C is fixed, but H is not. I'll see if I can figure out how to work that in to the code, but that still leaves the "YES" issue. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: @spsurfer, thank you for your clarification. Please have a look to my answer. I hope it can help you to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly....

Data in each sheet is something like this....
[image]

Expected result after running the code ...
[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Integer: Dim c As Integer

For Each sh In Sheets
    With sh.UsedRange
        r = .Rows.Count - 1
        c = .Rows(1).Find("UPC", lookat:=xlWhole).Column - 3
    End With

    With sh.Range("C2").Resize(r, c)
        .Replace 0, "", xlWhole
        .SpecialCells(xlConstants).Value = "Yes"
        .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = "No"
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

The code assumes that the value to be changed is always in between header SKU and UPC, where header SKU is fixed in column B but header UPC is not fixed. So the starting point of the range to be changed is fixed, which is range C2 on each sheet.

It loop to each sheet, and get how many rows is the usedrange of the looped sheet MINUS one as r variable, and get what is the column number of header SKU of the looped sheet MINUS three as c variable.

Then within the looped sheet range C2 resize into r and c, it replace the zero value with blank, then fill the special cell constant with YES and fill the special cell blank with NO.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Got an error at first, then realized that the "UPC" header was actually "UPC Code" in the source files. Thanks @karma

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
sub update_values()
   dim ws as worksheet
   'In the following line change text "integer" to "long" if total rows exceeds 32000
   dim lr as integer , i as integer, j as integer
   for each ws in thisworkbook.sheets
       ' use if condition with ws.name if you want to skip some sheets
       lr = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       for i = 2 to lr
           for j = 3 to 5 'C,D and E columns
                if ws.cells(i,3).value = 0 then
                     ws.cells(i,3).value = "No"
                else 'for non numeric use isnumeric function
                     ws.cells(i,3).value = "Yes"
                end if
           next j
       next i
       
   next ws
exit sub
```

Comment: What's your `j` for if you don't use it?

Comment: @spsurfer  This answer should work. Did it?

Comment: @alwyn-miranda Thank you. Running this results in all values in column "C" to change to "YES", even those that aren't supposed to, with no change to subsequent columns. Tried both dim as integer and dim as long, also

Comment: @Notus_Panda Assuming you're asking me and not Alwin, depending on the product category, 'J' may include different things depending on the number of availability columns. As noted in the Sheet 1 example above, 'J' contains MAP values, where a category with more visibility may have up to 2 more date columns, making 'J' the Details column.

Comment: @user10186832 Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Use this before setting the `.value` to Yes  ..  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearcontents